# Using vue material to build a service description page, however I am unable to cause the Text and Image to stack

Tags: css, vue.js, media-queries, vue-material

How do I ensure that when the screen is less than 768px. The Text and Image will stack on each other.

The md-layout with the md-column attributes that contain the content and images is to expand the whole page as the screen decreases to tablet, mobile and extra small screens if necessary.

```
<md-layout md-row md-sm-columns>

    <md-layout md-column="5"> <p class = "md-display-1"> Connect Soft documents </p>

  <p class = "">Allow documents that feed into each other to provide a consistent, untainted view of what your institution is doing.</p>

  </md-layout>


  <md-layout md-column="7">0</md-layout>



</md-layout>


<md-layout md-row md-sm-columns>

  <md-layout md-column = "7">

  <md-image md-src = "../assets/Statistics.png">

  </md-image>

  </md-layout>


  <md-layout md-column = "3"> <p class = "md-display-1"> Improve decision models</p>

  <p class = "">Use statistical modelling to identify patterns and anomalies in the data that can help you make better decisions.</p>


  </md-layout>



</md-layout>


<md-layout md-row md-sm-columns>

    <md-layout md-column="5"> <p class = "md-display-1">Search. Get what is important to You! </p>

  <p class = "">All notifications and documents are indexed and archived so that you can find what is needed at all times.</p>

  </md-layout>


  <md-layout md-column="7">0</md-layout>



</md-layout>

<md-layout md-row md-sm-columns>

  <md-layout md-column="5">


  </md-layout>


    <md-layout md-column="7"> <p class = "md-display-1"> Collaborate with other apps! </p>

  <p> Connect to the tools you need to prevent wasting time using so many apps </p>

  </md-layout>



</md-layout>
```

Comment: well you already tagged the answer : media queries. Usually (in a grid) you would define different "column sizes" for specific media queries that reflect the use cases of "phone, tablet, desktop, ..."

Comment: @FrankProvost I think the problem is that I really am unsure what to define in the queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you take an hour and play with http://vuematerial.io/#/ui-elements/layout. There you will find basic usage info but I think one must play with it to really understand it well enough.

I created one simple (possible) solution, if this is what you want;

```
<md-layout md-row md-sm-columns>

<md-layout md-column="7" md-flex-xsmall="100" md-flex-small="50" md-flex-medium="33">

  <md-image md-src="http://via.placeholder.com/800x600">

  </md-image>

</md-layout>


<md-layout md-column="3">
  <p class="md-display-1"> Improve decision models</p>

  <p class="">Use statistical modelling to identify patterns and anomalies in the data that can help you make better decisions.</p>


</md-layout>
```

So - using `md-flex-xsmall="100" md-flex-small="50" md-flex-medium="33"` attributes is one way to do it. Codepen here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jwRoYZ

---

But as allways - you can also assign your own class and target it via CSS directly (with help of Flex and mediaqueries);

```
 <md-layout md-row md-sm-columns>

<md-layout md-column="7" class="my-custom-class">

  <md-image md-src="http://via.placeholder.com/800x600">

  </md-image>

</md-layout>


<md-layout md-column="3">
  <p class="md-display-1"> Improve decision models</p>

  <p class="">Use statistical modelling to identify patterns and anomalies in the data that can help you make better decisions.</p>


</md-layout>
```

And some special CSS media queries;

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .my-custom-class {
    min-width: 100%;
    -ms-flex: 0 1 100%;
    flex: 0 1 100%;
  }
}
```

Codepen here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BZEeGw

---

*Keywords (to play with): CSS media queries, Flex, VueMaterial*